# select value from <select> field corresponding to value in previous <select> field

Tags: php, forms

I am having a form written in php. In this form there is  field named 'State' and the Options of this field are the names of the states.There is another  field named 'District' whose Options are the names of the District. The Options of the these two fields are being fetched from the database. There are about 28 states and there are about 12 Districts for each state. Now what is want is that when someone selects the state, then all the Districts corresponding to that state automatically appear in the District  field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an ajax call

on the select put `onchange="changedist(this.value)"`

and use the script function

```
function changedist(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }


  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","./dist.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and call this values in your page 
`<div id="dist">  here will returns the distrctis of the file dist.php</div>`

and dist.php

```
$q = $_GET[q];
$sql= "select * from dist where state = $q";


$query ....


echo ' <select name=dist>';
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))

{
echo " <option value=$result[key]>$result[dist]</option>";

}
```

so this will returns to your form page on the state change

Comment: I knew that I need to use ajax, but I just could not get how to implement as this is the first time I am going to use it. So thanks for the head start.

Comment: @Harbhag You should look into using a Javascript framework such as JQuery, they simplify things a lot and make them more portable.

Comment: @jacob Thanks for suggestion. I am already thinking of using that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need javascript to implement this nicely.

Here are two options:

1. Load the District select/options using ajax. i.e. When the State is changed an AJAX request is fired and reloads the District select box.
2. Loading all the Districts in, and hiding the ones that are not appropriate.

The benefit of option 2 is you don't need to wait for another request to complete before they can select the District. However it will require loading all the Districts up front. So 300ish options.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and concise explanation. Since its my first time with ajax so I needed some explanation with code.

Answer (score 2):

Create a javascript array mapping districts to states, e.g.:

```
var map = [];
map['state1'] = ['district1', 'district2', ... ];
map['state2'] = ['district13', 'district14', ... ];
```

Then the first select has an onChange function that clears the options from the second select and repopulates them from the predefined values in the array. In jQuery:

```
$('select[name=state]').change(function(){
    var state = $(this).val();
    var options = '';
    foreach (map[state] as district){
        options = options + '<option>'+district+'</option>';
    }
    $('select[name=district]').html(options);
});
```

Comment: The AJAX solution will work, but has many performance issues. This solution minimizes database load and network traffic. If the user has a slow connection, this will be much better. Since you're just learning, an AJAX solution may be easiest for you. Like Jacob, I also recommend jQuery for this.